# Search from two columns in other table and retrieve corresponding value from other column?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have the input tables `TblA` and `TblB`. I want to search values of columns `NUM` and `STR` from `TblA` within table `TblB`.

[image]

Below is my current code, that looks for values of column `NUM` of `TblA` within column `VALUES` of `TblB` and
gets the corresponding values of column `CODE_T`.

How to modify the step `Table.AddColumn()` in order to search the numeric parts (joined from right to left) of values in column `STR` of `TblA` within column `CODE_M` of `TblB`.

The numeric parts in inverse order I could get them in this way

```
    str1 = Text.Middle([CODE_M],14,3),
    str2 = Text.Middle([CODE_M],7,3),
    final_string_to_search = str1 & str2,
```

This is my expected output

[image]

This is my current code. Thanks in advance.

```
let
    TblA = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTI2MQaSSrE60UqRQIaRoRGMGwVkGBqamsP4ESCGjlJiUrJecWqyobm5XlpmkYmJkV55QWFKYkkiWJEbiiIDC0OQIktDY4SiWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TRS = _t, NUM = _t, STR = _t]),
    TblB = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("JYsxDsMwCEXvwpzB32ADY6oM7dAmipQqkuX7X6PY3d77PFojR6KFkMRZAp7Xl6kvjYCi4WpezQM+6zvNg1gJLRWFEbA/bsw9DxPJ0PF3nLvOmYVDs6PWHHCu2z+3mcFEeQSv7Xbq/Qc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [VALUES = _t, CODE_M = _t, CODE_T = _t]),

    Output
    = Table.AddColumn(
        TblA,
        "OUT",
        each
        let
            val = [NUM]
        in
            Text.Combine(Table.SelectRows(TblB, each Text.Contains(val, [VALUES]))[CODE_T], ",")
    )
in
    Output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

I chose to use `Join` rather than `SelectRows` because I think it executes more efficiently, (but I haven't actually tested it).

*I assumed there will be only a single match in TblB for any row in TblA. If that is not guaranteed, you need to specify what you want for output if multiple matches should occur. Current code will return only the first match.*

- Add a custom column to TblA for the reversed numbers in `STR`
- Left.Outer join between TblA and TblB with NUM and VALUES as the keys
- Then Left.Outer join between the first join and TblB using STRkey and CODE_M
- Remove the unneeded columns:

```
let
    TblAOrig = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTI2MQaSSrE60UqRQIaRoRGMGwVkGBqamsP4ESCGjlJiUrJecWqyobm5XlpmkYmJkV55QWFKYkkiWJEbiiIDC0OQIktDY4SiWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TRS = _t, NUM = _t, STR = _t]),

//add column with the reversed numbers in STR
//assumes the numbers are in 2nd and 3rd dot separated strings and at the end of those substrings
//  but the number of digits in the string are unspecified
    TblA  = Table.AddColumn(TblAOrig, "STRkey", 
        each if [STR]="" then null else
            let 
                Split1=List.Range(Text.Split([STR],"."),1,2),
                nums=List.Transform(Split1, 
                        (li)=>Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c)=>not List.Contains({"0".."9"},c),{"0".."9"})(li){1}),
                key=nums{1} & nums{0}
            in 
                key),

    TblB = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("JYsxDsMwCEXvwpzB32ADY6oM7dAmipQqkuX7X6PY3d77PFojR6KFkMRZAp7Xl6kvjYCi4WpezQM+6zvNg1gJLRWFEbA/bsw9DxPJ0PF3nLvOmYVDs6PWHHCu2z+3mcFEeQSv7Xbq/Qc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [VALUES = _t, CODE_M = _t, CODE_T = _t]),
    
    joinVALUES = Table.Join(TblA,"NUM",TblB,"VALUES",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    joinCODE_M = Table.NestedJoin(joinVALUES,"STRkey",TblB,"CODE_M","Join", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(joinCODE_M, "OUT", each if [CODE_T] <> null 
            then [CODE_T]
        else if List.Count([Join][CODE_T]) = 0
            then "NOT FOUND"
        else [Join][CODE_T]{0}, type text),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"STRkey", "VALUES", "CODE_M", "CODE_T", "Join"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***TblA***
[image]

***TblB***
[image]

***Result***
[image]

*If the output must be in a certain order, one can add an Index column to the TblA, and use that to sort the rows back to the original order.*

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution/explanation. A completely different way. For the reversed numbers in `STR`, the possible match could appear several times in `TblB`, but the answer would be select the first, so is ok. For values in `NUM` actually could be several possible and need to choose the best match. That best match would be the `lcf (Longest Common Prefix)` like here https://afteracademy.com/blog/longest-common-prefix//, but I don't know how to do it in PQ. I show an exact match in this post only to make it easy to understand. for the purpose of the output searched by me.

Comment: @RasecMalkic It is certainly possible to find the LCP in Power Query, using either the algorithms shown in your link, or others depending on the specifics of your examples. I suggest you post a separate question with comprehensive examples of input and desired output. Depending on the size of your database, developing an algorithm that is computationally efficient may also be important, but certainly doable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method

```
let
TblA = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTI2MQaSSrE60UqRQIaRoRGMGwVkGBqamsP4ESCGjlJiUrJecWqyobm5XlpmkYmJkV55QWFKYkkiWJEbiiIDC0OQIktDY4SiWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TRS = _t, NUM = _t, STR = _t]),
TblB = Table.Buffer( Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("JYsxDsMwCEXvwpzB32ADY6oM7dAmipQqkuX7X6PY3d77PFojR6KFkMRZAp7Xl6kvjYCi4WpezQM+6zvNg1gJLRWFEbA/bsw9DxPJ0PF3nLvOmYVDs6PWHHCu2z+3mcFEeQSv7Xbq/Qc=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [VALUES = _t, CODE_M = _t, CODE_T = _t])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(TblA,"OUT",(i)=>try Table.SelectRows(TblB, each i[NUM]=[VALUES] or Text.Middle(i[STR],14,3)=Text.Start([CODE_M],3))[CODE_T]{0} otherwise "NOT FOUND")        
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]